# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x+1)(x-1)e^{-(x+1)^2(x-1)^2}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am tring to solve the following integral:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(x+1)(x-1)e^{-(x+1)^2(x-1)^2}dx$$
So far I cannot think of a method for doing this other than numerically, And I have no proof that it has an elementary solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can express the result with the Bessel function

Comment: see here $$\frac{\pi 
   \left(I_{-\frac{5}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+
   I_{\frac{5}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}
   {4 \sqrt{e}}$$

Comment: Through substitution the integral should reduce to $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{ue^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{u+1}}du$, but I'm not sure if that makes it any easier.

Comment: @aleden How'd you get the lower bound (0)?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 by noticing that the original integrand is even

Comment: @aleden So you rewrote it as $2\int_0^{\infty}(x^2-1)e^{-(x^2-1)^2}dx$? It seems like you would then have to substitute $u=x^2-1$ to get the final version. Wouldn't that give a lower bound of -1?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 yes you are correct, my mistake. It should be $I=\int_{-1}^\infty \frac{ue^{-u^2}}{\sqrt{u+1}}du$

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ,aleden